# How can I remove CLMLsvc.exe from my startup?

Tags: boot

I have a process that runs at every boot and costs me about 30 seconds boot time each time that my computer starts.  Its a cyberlink media library application, but I dont want it to boot up every time my computer starts.

so I checked msconfig - I cannot find the it as a boot item, or a service listed there.  I do find it as a service listed in my services.

I dont want to delete the program I just want it to stop affecting my boot time

Answer (score 4):

**Using Autoruns to disable programs from launching at startup:**

1. Download and install [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902) from Windows Sysinternals. This program allows you to see everything that is loaded by your system during boot.
2. Start the program (autoruns.exe) and wait it to finish scanning your system. Shouldn't take long
3. Go to the Logon tab. You should see it listed there, possibly under the name *CyberLink MediaLibray Service*. But you should see the executable named under the "Image Path" column.
4. Untick it and it won't load next time you boot.

Answer (score 0):

**Blocking CLMLSvc.exe**

1. Open Control Panel -> Administrative Tools and run Task Scheduler.
2. In Task Scheduler Library window, double click on the CLMLSvc program
3. The CLMLSvc properties are opened, then in the Triggers tab delete start on Logon and save it.

You will block starting the CLMLSvc every logon and you don't need to uninstall this program.